# Latex References too small

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

Trying to submit a proposal to NSF.  The outline of my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}


\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath,latexsym, amsrefs, mathtools}

Stuff

\bibliography{references1023}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the bibliography by default is much smaller font and has 7-8 lines per inch. The NSF is rejecting it for having more than six lines per inch. Of course there is no page limit for the References section so I just need to make the font bigger. Alternately there is a .bbl file output if there is a way I could just take that off to the side and print out the references bigger that would work as well, since one separates out the references from the project description before submitting.

Comment: amsart at 11pt has a baselineskip of 13pt which is 72.27/13= 5.6 lines per inch.

Comment: show an example that has the smaller size then someone can debug, it is not the case by default.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `latexsym` and `amssymb`; load just the latter.

Comment: if I had a crystal ball it would suggest a misused abstract

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed a workaround, just compiled the bib separately with \large

\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\large
\input{test.bbl}
\end{thebibliography}